# How to calculate the mean between multiple rows that matchs by a given id

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I want to calculate the mean of mulptiple rows that have one single value where they match and store it in another csv file.
The given data is:

```
ID   salary days_of_work ...
1    2000   3            ...
1    1890   2            ...
1    2109   4            ...
2     .
2     .
2     .
2
3
3
...
```

And then obtain in another file, for every ID, one single row that contains the mean of the datas of the other columns like this:

```
ID   salary     days_of_work ...
1    1999.6667  3 ...
2    ...
3    ...
.
.
.
```

Update:

I tried to do this but for a file that has utc_time instead of ID

```
import pandas as pd


keep_col = ['utc_time','temperature','pressure','humidity','wind_direction','wind_speed/kph']
pd.read_csv('Gridpoints.csv', names=keep_col).to_csv("GridPoints/test.csv", index=False)



f=pd.read_csv("Gridpoints"+".csv")
df = f[keep_col]

df.groupby(['utc_time']).mean()

df.to_csv("GridPoints/test.csv", index=False)
```

So first what I do is getting a column deleted and then on the dataframe obtained, I want to do it for the utc_time column but it doesn't do anything

Comment: `df.groupby('ID').mean()`?

Comment: I'm trying to do this but the problem is that I have utc_time for the ID and it doesn't work

Comment: I updated my post for more details

Comment: `df.groupby(['utc_time']).mean()` returns a new `data frame`. do `df2 = df.groupby(['utc_time']).mean()` and then `df2.to_csv(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to group by ID and then calculate the mean.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')

df1 = df.groupby(['ID'], as_index= False)[['Salary', 'days']].mean()
print(df1)

ID       Salary  days
1  1999.666667   3.0
```